# Anonymous commands with Expl3

Tags: macros, expl3, arguments

The following code allows me to produce series easily (see examples below the code):

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \simpleseq { m m m } {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_inner_seq {,} {#3}
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_part_seq \l_inner_seq {\exp_not:n {#2}}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_part_seq {#1 \allowbreak}
}

\NewDocumentCommand \seq { O{,} O{\dots} D||{##1} s m s } {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_outer_seq {;} {#5}
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_final_seq \l_outer_seq {\exp_not:n {\simpleseq{#1}{#3}{##1}}}
  \IfBooleanT #4 { #2 #1 \allowbreak }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_final_seq {#1 \allowbreak #2 #1 \allowbreak }
  \IfBooleanT #6 { #1 \allowbreak #2 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[\seq[-] {1,2,3}\] % 1 - 2 - 3
\[\seq{1,2;5,6;10,11}\] % 1, 2, ..., 5, 6, ..., 10, 11
\[\seq*{1,2;5,6}\] % ..., 1, 2, ..., 5, 6
\[\seq[\ ][---]{1,2;5,6}*\] % 1 2 --- 5 6 ---

\[\seq |A_{##1}| {1,2;7,8}*\] % A_1, A_2, ..., A_5, A_6
% How to alter commands so that I can use either of these versions?
%\[\seq |A_{#1}| {1,2;7,8}*\]
%\[\seq |A_{\v}| {1,2;7,8}*\]

\end{document}
```

I'm concerned with the last example. I'm not happy with having to use `##1` as argument. I want either `#1` or `\v`.

Besides any advice about the quality of this code is welcome, I'm an Expl3 beginner ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define a temporary function:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_fabian_inner_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l_fabian_inner_out_seq
\seq_new:N \l_fabian_outer_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l_fabian_outer_out_seq

\NewDocumentCommand \seq { O{,} O{\dots} d|| s m s }
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   { \cs_set_eq:NN \__fabian_inner_process:n \use:n }
   { \cs_set_protected:Nn \__fabian_inner_process:n { #3 } }
  \IfBooleanT #4 { #2 #1 \allowbreak }
  \fabian_outer:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #5 }
  \IfBooleanT #6 { #1 \allowbreak #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \fabian_outer:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_fabian_outer_in_seq {;} {#3}
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_fabian_outer_out_seq \l_fabian_outer_in_seq
   {
    \exp_not:n { \fabian_inner:nn { #1 } { ##1 } }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_fabian_outer_out_seq {#1 \allowbreak #2 #1 \allowbreak }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \fabian_inner:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_fabian_inner_in_seq { , } { #2 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_fabian_inner_out_seq \l_fabian_inner_in_seq
   { \exp_not:n {\__fabian_inner_process:n { ##1 } } }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_fabian_inner_out_seq { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\seq[-] {1,2,3} % 1 - 2 - 3
\\
\seq{1,2;5,6;10,11} % 1, 2, ..., 5, 6, ..., 10, 11
\\
\seq*{1,2;5,6} % ..., 1, 2, ..., 5, 6
\\
\seq[\ ][\text{---}]{1,2;5,6}* % 1 2 --- 5 6 ---
\\
\seq |A_{#1}| {1,2;7,8}*
\\
\seq |A_{#1}| *{1,2;7,8}*
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, cleaner in many aspects, yet I'm not sure to understand why you introduced the `\fabian_outer` command. I learned a lot of things through your solution tho, thank you!

Comment: @FabianPijcke It's better to reserve the code in `\NewDocumentCommand` to simple tasks, deferring more complex ones to inner functions; typically, the main job of `\NewDocumentCommand` is to parse the arguments and do the appropriate calls to inner functions.

Answer (score 1):

The following modification works, but seems really really really unsafe <s>and I won't use it unless someone tells me it's a good idea (and gives me arguments so that I believe him :p)</s>

```
\NewDocumentCommand \simpleseq { m m m } {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_inner_seq {,} {#3}
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_part_seq \l_inner_seq {\exp_not:n {\def\v{##1}#2}}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_part_seq {#1 \allowbreak}
}
```

After some tests it seems not so unsafe ...

I just learned that `\def` binds locally (and not globally as I believed).

I made some tests where I `\def`'ed a macro `\v`, use it, use my commands, then use `\v` again, and all works as expected.

Anyway I'm still open to a more Latex3-ish solution :-)